# how to create property for another class better way

Tags: c#, wpf

I have class in a class. In view model i have system status property, in another class i am writing pc names by hand...for 150 pc's i create property for status PCs. What is the best way to make this clearly?

```
public class Computers
{
    public Computers()
    {
        computer1 = new SeriesViewModel();
        computer2 = new SeriesViewModel();
        computer3 = new SeriesViewModel();
        //over 150 computer
    }

    SeriesViewModel computer1 { get; set; }
    SeriesViewModel computer2 { get; set; }
    SeriesViewModel computer3 { get; set; }
    //over 150 computer
}

public class ComputerInfos: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ComputerInfos()
    {
    }

    private string compname;
    private string serialno;

    public string ComputerName
    {
        get { return compname; }
        set
        {
            compname= value;
            OnPropertyChange(this,ComputerName );
        }
    }
    public string SerialNumber
    {
        get { return serialno; }
        set
        {
            serialno= value;
            OnPropertyChange(this,SerialNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

In main window, I write over computers like below, but it takes too much effort and times. How can I make it easier?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Computers computer;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        computer = new Computers ();
        DataContext = computer;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        computer.computer1.ComputerName = "Computer 1";
        computer.computer1.SerialNumber = "1N-C1";
        computer.computer2.ComputerName = "Computer 2";
        computer.computer2.SerialNumber = "1N-C2";
        computer.computer3.ComputerName = "Computer 3";
        computer.computer3.SerialNumber = "1N-C3";
        // for each computers writing like this is bad
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this cases, we use `ObservableCollection<T>` class

You can check from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-6.0)

You can use `ObservableCollection` like this;

```
public class Computers
{
    public Computers()
    {
        ComputerInfo = new ObservableCollection<ComputerInfos>();

        for(int i = 0; i<150; i++)
        {
            ComputerInfo.Add(new ComputerInfos());
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ComputerInfos> ComputerInfo { get; }
}
```

For 150 Computers, you can use `For Loop` to each `ComputerInfos` class to `ComputerInfo` collection.
Then, you get or set each computer informations in your Main Windows get easier.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Computers computer;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        computer = new Computers ();
        DataContext = computer;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {          
        for (int i = 1; i <=150; i++)
        {
            computer.ComputerInfo[i-1].ComputerName = "Computer " + i.Tostring();
            computer.ComputerInfo[i-1].SerialNumber = "1N-C" + i.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is totally amazin answer to me. thank you very much! from now on i will use this collection

Comment: You are most welcome.

Comment: The property should be read-only: `public ObservableCollection<ComputerInfos> ComputerInfo { get; }`. Otherwise it should fire a change notification, i.e. the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Thank you for the correction and information @Clemens .

Comment: Just for fun, you could declare and initialize the collection in a single statement: `public ObservableCollection<ComputerInfos> ComputerInfo { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ComputerInfos>(Enumerable.Range(0, 150).Select(i => new ComputerInfos()));`

Comment: I have never used the last one before. It is so much useful.